# IIS URL rewrite from one site to another applies custom headers from the web.config of both sites

Tags: web-config, iis-8, content-security-policy, url-rewrite-module

I have two sites set up in IIS 8.5, which I'll call **test 1** (`test1.mydomain.com`) and **test 2** (`test2.mydomain.com`).

There is a URL rewrite rule in the test 1 web.config which rewrites `test1.mydomain.com/app/{route}` as `test2.mydomain.com/{route}`.

```
<rule name="Test 2 rewrite" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="^app(\/.*)?$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://test2.mydomain.com{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This is all working as expected, however I've found that when this rewrite rule is applied, the custom headers in the test 1 web.config are being included alongside the custom headers in the test 2 web.config. More specifically, this means I have *two* content security policy headers in the response.

This is causing issues, because test 1 has a stricter policy than test 2, so when accessing `test1.mydomain.com/app`, scripts and styles are failing to load.

I've tried wrapping the system.web and system.webServer for test 1 with a location tag, to see if I could prevent them from being inherited, but this has no effect:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
        ...
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

**When the url is rewritten to point to test 2, I only want the test 2 web.config to apply to that request. Is this even possible? If it's not possible, is the only solution to extend the CSP of site 1 to meet the requirements of site 2?**

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `<action type="Redirect"`, not the `<action type="Rewrite"`:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://test2.mydomain.com{R:1}" />
```

Comment: I would prefer this to remain a rewrite rather than changing it to a redirect, so that the user stays on the same subdomain from their perspective. Is it simply not possible to avoid the headers being included with a rewrite?

Comment: Remain to stay in the same domain is not a redirect, therefore IIS perform join web.configs from both sites. Have a look [this page](https://port135.com/configure-iis-to-ignore-web-config-files-in-application-subfolders/) (and links to a related posts), maybe it's possible to did what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to discovering the web.config <location> tag, and I've now wrapped the system.web and system.webServer sections of site 1 in an attempt to prevent them from being inherited, but sadly the headers are still being set on test 2. I've updated my question to include this.